# Reading from a file mixed with text and binary data in c#

Tags: c#

- I'm trying to read data from a file output by a label printer program for a test station.
- Most of the data is readable text that can be read using `StreamReader` and taking it a line at a time.
- Some of the lines need to have dynamic content replacing parts of the line, and I've got that working.
- The problem is that one of the printer commands is outputting a logo and the line starts with normal text and finishes with binary data.

  - If I try reading the line and processing the whole thing as a string, it messes up the logo. I thought I had a workaround by using the `Read()` method on that line and converting the result a character at a time from `Int32` to `byte`, but it ends up overflowing when the `Read()` method produces a value greater than `255`, which doesn't do well with `Convert.ToByte()`.
  - I wish that `StreamReader` had a `GetByte` method like `BinaryReader`, but it doesn't.
- Just looking for suggestions as I stumble toward a solution.

Comment: 1. Post a sample file
2. Post expected output (e.g. `string strContents = 'wahtever should be here from sample file'; byte[] binaryData = ... /// whatever should be here from sample file - 2`)
3. Post the code you're using to parse

Comment: Really new to this forum, not sure how to post a file. The trouble causing line starts with: BITMAP 15,12,17,56,1,  and then a string of 255 values, and other binary data. I need to get the output into byte[] format to send to the printer.

Comment: `using System.IO; var myFile = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\myfile.binary"); File.WriteAllText( @"C:\b64.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(myFile));` then open b64.txt, copy contents and paste in the post editor.

Comment: "*and I've got that working*" - doesn't seem like you have. There are many ways to get this wrong, and there are many solutions, though that entirely depends on what you are trying to store in the file (specifically) and why

Comment: Not trying to modify the file. Just open it, read the contents, add the text substitutions, convert the whole thing to byte[] to send to the printer. Everything is currently working except for the logo.

Comment: @user14128914 Does the file-format you're trying to read have a (published?) specification or BNF grammar? Generally speaking it's a bad idea to try to build your own file-format reader without knowing exactly how the file's data is composed. It's also very rare to see text and binary content mixed in a file without some form of structuring (e.g. binary length prefixing of text data or variable-length data) otherwise it's literally impossible to prove that a file-reader program is correct and won't misinterpret data.

Comment: Also, what text encoding is the file using? StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 which _may_ be incorrect for your application as the file might be using an ASCII-compatible codepage which isn't actually compatible with UTF-8, such as ISO 8859-1 - especially if you're talking about a label-printer's data stream (which tend to use old or obscure encoding or sometimes proprietary encoding schemes! (I'm looking at you, Zebra!))

Comment: Not sure what encoding the file is using. I've been using SlickEdit to view it, since it has a hex view mode. Apologies for posting an unhelpful question. And thanks for all replies.

Comment: If your file is ZPL , just send it straight to the printer port as bytes (assuming its a standard zebra thermal printer)

Comment: I need to make dynamic substitutions to some of the text fields that change with each device tested, so I can't just sent the file to the printer as is. If the file is read with BinaryReader and sent straight to the printer as bytes, then it all works. But I need to modify some of the text parts.

Comment: BTW, the printer is a TSC TTP-244CE.

Comment: Your sample "15,12,17,56,1" doesn't seem like "binary data", just text that contains digits that form comma-separated values

Comment: The binary data comes immediately after the last comma. The first character after that comma shows as 0xFF in SlickEdit. I believe that sequence of numbers is determining where the logo should be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `BinaryReader` instead of `StreamReader`.

  - You can use `BinaryReader` to read text just like `StreamReader` too - the only catch is that you'll need to bring your own `ReadLine` as an extension-method, but here's an example below.
- It is *technically* possible to use both `StreamReader` and `BinaryReader` on the same `Stream` concurrently - but you need to be familiar with the internals of both and how their read-buffer and stream-reading behaviour works. So I don't recommend using this approach at all.
- Use the `BinaryReaderExtensions` below to have `ReadLine`, and switch to binary methods when you get to the binary part of the file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public static class BinaryReaderExtensions
{
    public static String ReadLine( this BinaryReader reader )
    {
        if( reader is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
        if( reader.IsEndOfStream() ) return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while( ReadChar( reader, out Char c ) )
        {
            if( c == '\r' || c == '\n' )
            {
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append( c );
            }
        }

        if( sb.Length > 0 ) return sb.ToString();

        return null;

        char character;
    }

    private static Boolean ReadChar( BinaryReader reader, out Char c )
    {
        if( reader.IsEndOfStream() ) return false;
        c = reader.ReadChar();
        return true;
    }

    public static Boolean IsEndOfStream(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return reader.BaseStream.Position == reader.BaseStream.Length; 
    }
}
```

Example:

```
using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( "file.dat", FileMode.Read, etc ) )
using( BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader( fs, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
{
    // I assume the first 5 lines are text:
    List<String> linesOfText = new List<String>();
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        String line = rdr.ReadLine();
        if( line is null ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Encountered premature EOF in text section." );
        linesOfText.Add( line );
    }

    // And after the 5th line it's a 512 byte blob of binary data (for example):
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ 512 ];
    Int32 bytesRead = rdr.Read( buffer, index: 0, count: 512 );
    if( bytesRead != buffer.Length ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Encountered premature EOF (in binary section)." );
}
```